# remove class and add class when an element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is already working, what i want to achieve is that when title is
clicked i want to remove the class of the i tag which is fa-toggle-off
and replace it with fa-toggle-on. I already achieve this the problem is
all of the i tag is affected.

```
 <div class="row package-row">
      <div class="global-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="switch1" name="switch1" class="switch" />
            <label for="switch1">Hide Packages</label>
      </div><!--end of global-switch-->
      <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="header-details">
                   <h3 id="toggle-h3-package"><i class="fa fa-toggle-off" style="margin-right: 10px;"></i>TITLE</h3>
                   <p>DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
            <div class="global-control" id="global-control">
                   CONTENT
            </div>
      </div>            
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.toggle-h3-package').click(function(){
                $(this).parent().next('.global-control').animate({
                    height:'toggle',
                    opacity:'toggle'
                },{
                    duration: 5000,
                    specialEasing: {
                      width: "linear",
                      height: "easeOutBounce"
                    }
                });
            });
            $('.toggle-h3-package').click(function() {
                var target = $('.header-details .toggle-h3-package i');

                if (target.hasClass('fa-toggle-off')) {
                    $('.header-details .toggle-h3-package i').removeClass('fa-toggle-off').addClass('fa-toggle-on');
                }
                else {
                   $('.header-details .toggle-h3-package i').removeClass('fa-toggle-on').addClass('fa-toggle-off');
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please use some basic punctuation in your question text.

Comment: Sorry Roope . forgot to use punctuation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should narrow your selector:

`var target = $('.header-details .toggle-h3-package i');` - this will find all `i` elements on the page. And you need only `i` that is in you clicked `.toggle-h3-package`. Use `find` method with `this`:

```
$('.toggle-h3-package').click(function() {
    var target = $( this ).find( 'i' );
    // your code here
```

Also you can use `toggleClass` function without checking if element has some class:

```
target.toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is what i did as you suggested..

```
 $('.toggle-h3-package').click(function() {
                    var target = $( this ).find( 'i' );
                        target.toggleClass('fa-toggle-on fa-toggle-off');
                });
```